# RAILS: Accessing the current controller from inside a lib class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller I have:

```
@list = ListView.new()
```

The template contains:

```
= @list.render
```

And in `lib/list_view.rb` I have:

```
class ListView

    def render
        controller_name.inspect
    end

end
```

When I run this code I get a `undefined local variable or method 'controller_name'` error. I'm still new to Rails but I'm sure there's a way to do this as will_paginate does it here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view.rb#L92

It does appear that will_paginate might be a module and not a class? I'm missing something...

Comment: The difference is that the `will_paginate` code is a mixin that is included into a class that has a controller instance variable. You are creating a class which doesn't have any existing variable that matches the variable name you are calling, which is why you are getting the undefined variable name. Passing the controller into the constructor of your class is a way to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do something like:

```
class ListView

    def initialize(controller)
      @controller = controller
    end

    def render
      controller_name.inspect
    end

  private 

    def controller()   @controller    end

    def controller_name
      controller.controller_name
    end

end
```

Then in your controller, do:

```
@list = ListView.new(self)
```

I'm guessing that you're going for the presenter pattern. If so, you'll want to watch Ryan Bates great [RailsCast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHsq6aFlP0U) on the subject where you'll learn how to get your presenter to actually render something.